# Pdo_informix and XAMPP on windows

Tags: php, apache, pdo, informix

This is my last resort because I'm desperate , I searched the Internet , IBM and but no luck.

My problem is that I can not connect using php because the connector for charging according apache, reports this:

> 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ifx.php:3

The php_pdo_informix.dll is in the folder ext of php, the php.ini is changed and.. the CSDK (Client SDK of IBM) connect and give me all the data I need.

I'm trying to extract data from a VM to my php file.  What do I do ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your post to correct English issues.  If I have changed your meaning, then please edit it.  I have also marked down the error message using > at the start of the line.

Comment: Make sure you System PATH environment variable contains the %INFORMIXDIR%\bin directory. 'php_pdo_informix.dll' needs to load some libraries from that directory (e.g. iclit09b.dll).it. If it's not, and the PDO driver can't find the libraries, you will get that error.  Also, you need to have a matching version of all the components. If your Apache is 64-bit, you will need a 64-bit version of the Informix PDO driver and a 64-bit version of CSDK. The suffix in the CSDK version will tell you what you have right now. 'F' in 4.10.FC10 means 64-bit, 'T' in 4.10.TC10 means 32-bit.